# Java handle invalid request Mapping urls including decodings

Tags: java, spring, api, exception, request-mapping

in my apiController, I have

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api/v1/myservice")
@Slf4j
public class APIController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/validAPI1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String validAPI1() {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

I want to catch invalid incoming API requests, such as `/api/v1/myservice/random124` , and this can be done by adding a method at the end:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String handleInvalidAPIReq() {
    return "watched and handled";
}
```

This has 2 problems, does not catch special characters such as `%` in URL, and does not take care of input URLs. An example I'm trying to fight against: `/api/v1/myservice/%uff0e%uff0e%u2215%7bFILE%7d/abc12`

Are there existing libraries or methods I can use to catch invalid incoming API requests please? Could you help with examples?  Appreiate tons.

Comment: If you want to pass `%` in URL then properly encode it as `%25`

Comment: What is ``invalid incoming API requests``?

Answer (score 3):

The common solution for handling bad requests is to set `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` in `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` class. You didn't mentioned which type of application you wrote, simple war archive with spring-mvc dependency or spring boot styled application.

For simple spring-mvc application, you can set that property in **web.xml** file:

```xml
    ...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    ...
```

For spring boot application, you just need to set config property:

```xml
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

In both cases, `DispatcherServlet` will throw `NoHandlerFoundException` exception, in order to handle this exception, you need to add the `ExceptionHandler` class as follows::

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(404).body("Error occurred");
    }

}
```

**Note:** When you enable `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` property, you should remember about static resources, and add custom mappings for them, otherwise the resources will not be found.
Configure static resources (Spring Boot):

```xml
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/static/
```

or if there are no static resources:

```xml
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. The services I use wrapps spring configs and I cannot set config as do not see a web.xml. ControllerAdvice is very helpful. I tried to setup above code but it did not hit the break point even if I used the most generic @ExceptionHAndler(Exception.class). I'm trying to explore ResponseEntity. Please help share more ideas. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify phrase: "The services I use wrapps spring configs", Anyway you use ```DispatcherServlet```, otherwise ```RequestMapping``` annotations will not work. There are few ways to define ```DispatcherServlet``` one of ways is ```web.xml``` and starting from Servlet 3.0, ```DispatcherServlet``` can be configured programmatically by implementing or extending classes: ```WebAppInitializer```, ```AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer```, ```AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer```.
Please check in witch way ```DispatcherServlet``` is configured in your project.

Comment: Your implemented ```ExceptionHandler``` (as you mentioned above) doesn't work, because ```DispatcherServlet``` doesn't throw exception, there is only one way to process unmapped urls, you should find place where is ```DispatcherServlet``` defined and add attribute for throwing exceptions